# Gordon Dickson, Man from Earth

Tags: gordon-dickson

There is a series of short stories by Gordon Dickson. In one if the stories, called "Danger-Human" it describes how a human is abducted by aliens and submitted to various tests. The reason for this is that humans have, in the past, taken over the known galaxy, only to be defeated, with only seed colonies surviving. Anyhow, at the end of the story, the human somehow escapes and gets past an unbeatable force field and the aliens can only marvel at how he did it. It is very vague as to how he made it passed this "energy barrier." Can someone give a better explanation of this ending?

Comment: Clarify 'Man from Earth' in the question title.  Is that supposed to be the name of the anthology ?  If so, can't find anything by Dick under that.  However, there is an [anthology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_from_Earth_%28collection%29) of stories by Gordon Dickson published under that title.  It contains a short of the same name but I can't find any info on the short itself.

Comment: Doesn't sound depressing enough to be a Philip K. Dick story :v

Comment: I'm terribly sorry about the misinformation. Gordon Dickson is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @user14111 for the link.

Now that I've read the story, it seems to me that this is a question that shouldn't be answered. Like "The Problem of Cell 13", the story is set up much like a riddle or a magic trick -- how can our hero escape from the inescapable prison? And like the two alternative solutions to Cell 13, the escape through the energy barrier is left to the reader to puzzle over.

There *is* a way he could have done it. At the end of the story, the three aliens conclude that the unique human power is the ability to keep on looking for impossible solutions; any one of them, or any member of any other known race, would have seen that escape was impossible and accepted the fact. He could **not** get through the barrier.

> "But he *did* get out! You don't mean . . ." the commander's voice
> faltered and dropped. The three stood caught in a sudden silence like
> stone. Slowly, as if drawn by strings controlled by an invisible hand,
> they turned as one to stare up into the empty sky and space beyond.
>
> "You mean—" the commander's voice tried again, and died.
>
> "Exactly!" whispered the doctor.

This can be read two ways. Either A) they have verified that escape through the energy barrier was impossible, yet the man did it, therefore the human race really is utterly unstoppable, or B) they just realized how he did it.

Riddles and magic tricks are much less entertaining if you don't solve them yourself, but here's a hint for those who want it:

> When did he smile?

Comment: As someone who can continually miss the obvious, please explain (B).

Answer (score 4):

While it may be the intent of the story to purposefully not provide any explanation of his escape through the defensive screen, so as to drive home the idea that humans can do the impossible by sheer determination and force of will, I think there is a possible explanation alluded to in the story (which [Beta hints at](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/46052/2287)). Since it will be largely impossible to correctly spoiler-proof the following interpretation, I'll just warn readers to stop here and read no further if you'd like to maintain the mystery...

There are a few key statements made by the aliens that should first be noted (emphasis mine):

> *(when Eldridge is first imprisoned)* "You were literally taken apart physically, after your capture; and as literally put back together again. We are advanced in the organic field, and certain things are true of all life forms. I supervised the work on you, myself. You will find that you are, for all practical purposes, immortal and irretrievably sane. This will be your home forever, and you will find that **neither death nor insanity will provide you a way of escape**."
>
> *(after Eldridge has an apparent mental breakdown)* "You tried hard—" said the doctor. "But you see, you didn't make it. **There's no way out *that* way for you**."
>
> *(after Eldridge escapes)* "Didn't we do it, we three? The legend told us not to touch them, not to set a spark to the explosive mixture of their kind. And we went ahead and did it, you, and you, and I. And now we've sent forth an enemy—safely into the safe hiding place of space, in a ship that can take him across the galaxy, supplied with food to keep him for years, **rebuilt into a body that will not die**, with star charts and all the keys to understand our culture and locate his home again, using the ability to learn we have encouraged in him."

There is a point when the doctor states that Eldridge isn't truly immortal, "only practically speaking", and that there are still apparent limits on how long he is able to live. But this still suggests that Eldridge has a sort of Wolverine-esque ability to resist death and aging, given to him by the aliens for the purpose of studying him for as long as possible. I believe this gives Eldridge the ability to survive the defensive screen, something Eldridge seems to realize after his mental breakdown (when he starts smiling). The aliens assumed that escape was impossible, and indeed it may have been for any normal human, but they themselves made Eldridge "supernormal" with their organic tinkering. Lacking the exceptional imagination and problem-solving ability of humans, the aliens were unable to envision how their own actions undermined their assumption.

So, in short, I think there are two themes/concepts at play here. One is "human exceptionalism", whereby humans have a unique, innate capacity to imagine solutions that other species couldn't, thereby making them able to perform feats other species would deem impossible or unimaginable. The second is the self-fulfilling prophecy, whereby the aliens, believing that humans are dangerous and possess "some capability above the normal", treat one in a way that causes him to realize his full potential and become the threat they fear so much. I believe this is the realization the aliens make in the end.

Comment: That's not what I had in mind at all, and I would be **very** disappointed if it somehow turned out to be the author's intent.

Comment: @Beta: Really? I honestly thought that was what you were alluding to. Now I'm quite curious about what you had in mind. :)

Comment: @Beta - Why not simply tell us what you think the explanation is?

Comment: This was essentially the same explanation that popped into my head when I first read the story, years ago. (Although I wasn't sure that Dickson wasn't going for a "sheer willpower produced a miracle" scenario, and Adamant also makes a good case for his theory.)

Answer (score 3):

The Gordon Dickson story with this plot is an illustration of the popular "Human Exceptionalism Paradigm".

> [The view (paradigm) that humans are different from all other organisms, all human behaviour is controlled by culture and free will, and all problems can be solved by human ingenuity and technology. See also anthropocentrism.](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095949791)

So no explanation was needed (or provided) for *how* the force field was bypassed. A human being can do the impossible if he sets his mind to it, just *because* he is a human being.

Edit:
The indefatigable user14111 id'd the story in comments along with the link to the text - ["Danger--Human!"](https://www.baen.com/Chapters/0743471741/0743471741.htm) by Gordon Dickson.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however; in the story the human overcomes other obstacles in a more traditional manner. The reasons given in the story are totally believable other than the one given about the force field.

Comment: Just the one miracle, huh? That's the point, though. Nothing, not even the impossible, will stop Mankind.

Answer (score 3):

**He probably jumped over the barrier.**

The evidence in the story suggests that the barrier is a ring, not a dome or a sphere:

> His position was such that he could see out the window and over the
>   weaving **curtain** of the barrier that **ringed** his building, to the
>   landing field. After a while one of the large ships landed and when he
>   saw the three members of its crew disembark from it and move, antlike,
>   off across the field toward the buildings at its far end, he smiled
>   again.

Further:

> Eldridge looked. Out beyond, and surrounding the building the shallow
>   trench no longer lay still and empty under the sun. It now spouted a
>   vertical wall of flickering, weaving distortion, like a barrier of
>   heat waves.

A dome isn't **vertical**, of course.

All of this suggests that the barrier is a straight, tall wall.

Note, especially, that he could see *over* the barrier. Since everything is described as flat, this suggests that it was not overly high, and again that it wasn't a dome.

The  aliens look at the sky afterward, or upward, which suggests that has something to do with how he escaped:

> "But he did get out! You don't mean . . ." the commander's voice
>   faltered and dropped. The three stood caught in a sudden silence like
>   stone. Slowly, as if drawn by strings controlled by an invisible hand,
>   they turned as one to stare up into the empty sky and space beyond.
>
> "You mean—" the commander's voice tried again, and died.
>
> "Exactly!" whispered the doctor.

Since he couldn't have taken a ship (they were in the field beyond the barrier), this suggests that he got over by himself.

There's some hints that he took a running jump, both from his dreams:

> won the fifth grade seventy-five yard dash . . .

And from what he did after getting past the moat but before getting past the barrier:

> He began to run—

We also know he's good at jumping, since he jumped 10 feet across the moat.

As further evidence, while this story is certainly extolling the virtues of humanity, it's not humanity in *general*, really, but more a specific *kind* of human. A pragmatic man, specifically, without formal education, but with a can-do spirit.

> It's not what he did," said the academician, "but the fact that he did
>   it. No member of another culture that we know would have even
>   entertained the possibility in their minds. Don't you see—he
>   disregarded, he denied the fact that escape was impossible."

It's not really about an intellectual, in other words. The aliens, if anything, are stand-ins for intellectuals, with their advanced technology and highly scientific outlook. As such, the idea of taking the risk of jumping over the barrier would fit with the theme, whereas any clever use of physics or technology would be right out.

Further, it would fit with how he overcame the other obstacles, which involved physical strength (the metal arm), and more broadly reliance on his body in general (the stomach acid).

As the doctor said, the (supposedly) impressive thing isn't that he jumped over the barrier. It's that he would conceive of the idea of jumping over the barrier that he had already been told was impossible to get through, and would kill him if he tried. None of the aliens would conceive of taking this risk. If this seems not terribly impressive, let's remember that this *is* a human exceptionalism story.

Answer (score 1):

As ImaginaryEvents stated, he escapes through a use of the Human Exceptionalism Paradigm and in this story- that's exactly what the aliens are looking for.

> "I will go on. There is something about your people that we are very
>   anxious to discover. We have been, and intend to continue, studying
>   you to find it out. So far—I will admit quite frankly and freely—we
>   have not found it; and the concensus among our best minds is that you,
>   yourself, do not know what it is. Accordingly, we have hopes of . . .
>   causing . . . you to discover it for yourself. And for us."

Humans almost took over the galaxy three times, just by being as resourceful and tenacious as Eldridge was in his escape. Whatever he does to pass through the energy field, is exactly what they were looking for, and exactly what Eldridge had no idea he could do.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading a story once, with the title you first mentioned.  As far as I recall the aliens capture a human specimen and, against the advice of a worried alien scientist(?) who wants him destroyed, keep him in a cell with the sign 'Danger - Human' displayed.  Someone queries this, because the human looks harmless.  Eventually (I think over many years, because his life is artificially prolonged) he escapes from the cell by gradually dissolving the lock(?) with his regurgitated stomach acids and then...overcomes something else, probably your force field, by a method I can't recall!  And flees. Sorry, the stomach acids thing stayed with me but not the rest. There is a Gordon R. Dickson story of this title, it may be the one we both remember.

Comment: You are correct. That's the one.

Comment: Wow! I'm glad my question generated the responses that it has. Thank you to everyone who has posted to this point. I am satisfied with all the comments so far and realize that I may have been looking for an easy answer when in fact I believe that Dickson's purpose was to get the reader to think about it more deeply, based on the fact that almost everything else in the story is pretty cut and dry except for the particular point in question.